# HTML select element does not update its selected value on touch start in iOS?

Tags: javascript, html, touch, dom-events, touchstart

I am seeing discrepancies in iOS safari with how select elements are handled between the ontouchstart and onmousedown events where the selected index of a focused select element is updated in another element's "mouse down" event handler, but is not updated in another element's "touch start" event handler.

Play around with the jsbin on mobile safari by changing the value of the select element without pressing done, tabbing, etc and then pressing one of the two buttons. You should see the select tag go back to its original value with the "touch start" button, and persist the new value with the "mouse down" button. Note that the onchange fires for the mouse down button, but not the touch start.

https://jsbin.com/felufudeke/1/edit?js,output

```
let selectElement = document.getElementById('select');
let touchStartButton = document.getElementById('touchStart');
let mouseDownButton = document.getElementById('mouseDown');

touchStartButton.ontouchstart = function (e) {
    // on change has not fired yet...
    selectElement.blur();
}

mouseDownButton.onmousedown = function (e) {
    // on change HAS fired if iOS selector value was different
    selectElement.blur();
}
```

Is this intentional and expected from the browser? I was personally expecting both "touch start" and "mouse down" to fire "change" of the focused select element, as I could not find any documentation with the details on this behavior.

Is there any way in the ontouchstart handler that I can get the current "active" selection of the iOS selector?

Comment: If they were the same, there wouldn't be any need for having both.

Comment: @ScottHunter AFAIK touch start is fired only on touch devices, and mouse down is fired for both touch and non-touch devices. They fundamentally sound like they would be fired together, so the need in my mind would be if the programmer needed to do some special event handling specific for touch devices.